# Pandas : histogram with fixed width

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have data which I want to do an histogram, but I want the histogram to start from a given value and the width of a bar to be fixed. For example, for the serie [1, 3, 5, 10, 12, 20, 21, 25], I want, instead of

```
>>> p.Series([1, 3, 5, 10, 12, 20, 21, 25]).hist(bins=3).figure

#  |       |
#  |   |   |
#  |   |   |
#  0   8.5 17
```

[image: Current histogram]

I want the bars to have a width of 10 :

```
|       |
|   |   |
|   |   |
0   10  20
```

How can I do that ?

EDIT : I eventually get what I wanted [image: good hist]

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you give a series which can replicate this issue (and maybe include a figure)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think

```
p.Series([1, 3, 5, 10, 12, 20, 21, 25]).hist(bins=[0, 10, 20, 30]).figure
```

will do what you want. Alternately you can do

```
p.Series([1, 3, 5, 10, 12, 20, 21, 25]).hist(bins=3, range=(0,30)).figure
```

See [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist) for `hist` and the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) for `np.histogram`.

I suspect you are also running into some issues because it is labeling the *center* of the bins, not the edges.

Comment: That is what exactly what I wanted, I didn't know that bins could have a list argument. Thanks !

Comment: @oao It always pays to read the documentation ;)

Comment: I read it but bins was only presented with an integer argument at [the Pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html). It is only explained in the  [matplotlib doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist)

Comment: @oao Ah, fair enough.  I think all of the `pandas` plotting is actually a very thin wrapper of `matplotlib` so it is worth looking upstream to understand what it is really doing.