# Python: Histogram - Create uequal bins/axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, clip

Note,this question is related to  :[[Defining bin width/x-axis scale in Matplotlib histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176385/defining-bin-width-x-axis-scale-in-matplotlib-histogram]).
I have a data that looks like this

```css
 Time               Pressure
    1/1/2017 0:00       5.8253
    ...                     ...
    3/1/2017 0:10       4.2785
    4/1/2017 0:20       5.20041
    5/1/2017 0:30       4.40774
    6/1/2017 0:40       4.03228
    7/1/2017 0:50       5.011924
    12/1/2017 1:00      3.9309888
```

I would like to plot a histogram such that it looks like this.The intervals be like- [0-40,60,65,70,75,80]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523545/pandas-histogram-with-fixed-width&ved=2ahUKEwjD776cypjbAhVFYpoKHVAFDi8QFjACegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw3an28H8RSbLKxFzpqu4fIT

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak: I want the values [0,40,60,65,70,75,80] on the x-axis similar to the image

Comment: Have you tried putting up a code together that does it? why not posting it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the histogram using `numpy.histogram()` and then plot it using `Axes.bar()`. The ticks can then be adjusted using `Axes.set_ticklabels()`. Here an example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#some fake data:
data = np.random.normal(70,20,[100])

#the histogram
dist, edges = np.histogram(data,bins=[0,40,60,65,70,75,80])

#the plot    
fig,ax = plt.subplots()    
ax.bar(
    np.arange(dist.shape[0]), dist, width=1, align = 'edge',
    color = [1,0,0,0.5], edgecolor=[1,0,0,1], lw = 2,
    )
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(edges.shape[0]))
ax.set_xticklabels(edges)

plt.show()
```

The whole thing looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.